# How do I get KnowledgeArticleViewStat data from a Visualforce page via SQL queries?

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am trying to display information about Knowledge Articles on my page. One of the things I want to display is the most viewed article stat.

I have a Visualforce Apex component that looks like this:

```
<apex:component controller="Component_Query" access="global">
  <apex:attribute name="QueryString" type="String" required="true" access="global" assignTo="{!queryString}"
    description="A valid SOQL query in string form." />

    <apex:variable value="{!results}" var="results"/>
    <apex:componentBody />
</apex:component>
```

I have a Visualforce page that looks like this:

```
<apex:page >
    <table id="articles">
        <knowledge:articleList articleVar="article" sortBy="mostViewed" pageSize="5">
        <tr>
            <td>{!article.articlenumber}</td>
            <td><a target="_parent" href="{!URLFOR($Action.KnowledgeArticle.View, article.id)}">{!article.title}</a></td>
            <td>{!article.articletypelabel}</td>
            <td>{!article.lastpublisheddate}</td>
            <td>
                <c:Query_component queryString="SELECT NormalizedScore FROM KnowledgeArticleViewStat WHERE ParentId = '{!article.id}'">
                <apex:repeat value="{!results}" var="result">
                </apex:repeat>
                </c:Query_component>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </knowledge:articleList>
    </table>
</apex:page>
```

I put the Visualforce Page into a tab. When I view the page, all the information about the knowledge articles show up except for the information about the most viewed stat. How do I see this stat?

Comment: Very interesting how you're using the custom Query_component, care to share you're design decision in using that instead of just querying in controller?

Comment: @Ralph what do you mean by "just querying in controller"?

Comment: Usually if you're following MVC design principles, the visualforce page (the view) just displays the data, where as the controller handles querying the data.  In this case "controller" is an apex class that drives your visualforce page (yours doesn't have one) and is usually where you do a database query.  The c:query component lets you specify the query in the page.  Hadn't seen someone do it like that before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using in my Visualforce page:

```
    <c:Query_component queryString="SELECT NormalizedScore, Id, ParentId FROM KnowledgeArticleViewStat WHERE Channel='Csp'">
        <apex:variable value="{!results[articleid]}" var="result"/>
            <span class="inlinesparkline">100, {!result}</span>
    </c:Query_component>
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add an output for the view stat. You must add an `<apex:outputText>` tag inside the repeat to show the value.

`<apex:outputText>{!result.NormalizedScore}</apex:outputText>`